# Spring data JPA null record check?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository class where I have extended JPARepository and created a query that gets a list of records from a table.

```
ICA ica = null;
ica = brRepository.findByNameAndId(name , id);
```

Now when this `ica = brRepository.findByNameAndId(name , id);` is executed and suppose there is no record in the table what will be the value for `ica`

Will it be null only ?

Basically I want to compare the `ica` with null if its null then log something else log another thing.
Is it right way to compare or what can be the safe operation

```
if(ica == null){
System.out.println("Null");
}
else{
System.out.println("there is one record");
}
```

Comment: "*Will it be null only ?*" - I am not entirely sure what you mean, but why not try it out?

Answer (score 3):

According to the new versions of Spring-Data-JPA it is supported and encouraged the use of Optionals.

```
Optional<ICA> ica = brRepository.findByNameAndId(name , id);


if(ica.isPresent()){
  System.out.println("there is one record");
} else{
  System.out.println("Null");
}
```

You must also modify the method defined in the repository to return `Optional<ICA> findByNameAndId`

Comment: I think the condition should be reverse ```if(ica.isPresent()){System.out.println("there is one record");
} else{
System.out.println("null");
}```

Comment: @Learners correct I updated :)